# IOS Thread in UIView can not be release

Tags: ios, multithreading, uiview

i make a AdView extends UIView like this

AdView:

```
//nerver call dealloc when adview release
-(void)dealloc
{
   //stop thread
   bStart = NO;
   //...
   [super dealloc];
}
-(id)init
{ 
    //.....
    bStart = YES;
    //the self will retain by NSThread,i try to call [self performBackground..:onThrad] or timer the same too.
    NSThread* thead = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTagert:self ...:@select(onThread)];
    [thread start];
    [thread release];
}
-(void)onThread
{
   while(bStart)
   {
       //....
    }
}
```

the controller

```
{
    AdView* view = [[AdView alloc] init];
    view.delegate = self;// i am ture delegate is not retain
    [self.view addSubView:view];

    [view release]
}
```

Adview has never to call dealloc when contoller release, 
who konws how to fix it.

Comment: Are you using ARC? Because it looks like you're not (as you're calling `release`), but you also never call `[super dealloc]` in your `dealloc` method. You *must* call `[super dealloc]`.

Comment: @lxt NO,i had call [super dealloc],i will fix my qustion

Comment: What are your trying to do exactly? What's the requirement for directly using an `NSThread`?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella like some animation and network

Comment: @Fogmeister thanks,But I'm not accustomed to using the ARC~~so anyway?

Comment: Use GCD, instead of messing with threads.

Comment: ARC = don't have to get accustomed to it. It's recommended by Apple and it means you no longer have to worry about memory management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others noted you are passing `self` to the target initialization which retains it. That's why you have an extra retain causing the object not being deallocated.

That said, let me give you two pieces of advice here:

1. **Use ARC**. It's 2013, we suffered with manual reference counting for about enough time.
2. **Use GCD**. It's 2013, we suffered with manual threads management for about enough time.

A modern version of your code would look like

```
- (instancetype)init { 
    //...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [self doStuffAsynchronously];
    });
    //...
}

- (void)doStuffAsynchronously { ... }
```

#### EDIT

As JFS advices in the comments, if you need to start and stop the background execution you should consider using a `NSOperation` within a `NSOperationQueue`. A naive (but still functional) implementation would be:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSOperationQueue * operationQueue;

//...

- (instancetype)init {
    //...
    self.operationQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
    [operationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [self doStuffAsynchronously];
    }];
    //...
}

- (void)doStuffAsynchronously { ... }

- (void)stopDoingStuff {
    [self.operationQueue cancelAllOperations];    
}
```

A neater approach, though, would be to subclass `NSOperation`, starting it by adding it to a queue and stopping it by invoking `stop`.

Comment: If you need to stop background threads the use of `NSOperationQueue` is a better choice.

Comment: Conceptually it's not right to use a weak reference to self here. As long as the method `doStuffAsynchronously` runs the target should not go away.

Answer (score 0):

[The thread retains the target](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSThread/initWithTarget%3aselector%3aobject%3a) `self` in `start`. So the object can not go away as long as the thread runs.

The controller should stop the thread by calling something like `adView.bStart = NO;` (which of course you have to implement).

Comment: You have to stop the thread somehow. It's the controller's job to figure out when.